# if $n=4k+r$ with $0 ≤ r ≤ 3$ then $7^n ≡7^r \pmod{ 10}$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let k be a positive integer. Prove that if $a ≡ b (mod m)$ then $a^k ≡ b^k (mod m)$. Then, use that  to show that if $n=4k+r$ with $0 ≤ r ≤ 3$ then $7^n ≡7^r (mod 10)$.

I have proven the first result using induction but I am not able to think of 2nd one.

Answer (score 2):

The first result also follows from $$a^k-b^k=(a-b)\left(a^{k-1}+a^{k-2}b+\cdots+b^{k-1}\right)$$

Then $49\equiv -1\pmod{10}$, so $7^4= 49^2\equiv (-1)^2=1\pmod{10}$,

so $\left(7^4\right)^k\equiv 1^k= 1\pmod{10}$. Also remember the product rule:

If $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$ and $c\equiv d\pmod{m}$, then $ac\equiv bd\pmod{m}$.

Proof: Hint: $ac-bd=(a-b)c+b(c-d)$.

$7^{n}= \left(7^{4}\right)^k\cdot 7^r\equiv 1\cdot 7^r= 7^r\pmod{10}$